# Google Play Services Unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to add Google Play Services using the Jar Resolver that Google put out - https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver to create a plugin we can re-use to easily add Google Play Services to our projects.

I've created a copy of their example dependency class:

```
// <copyright file="GPGSDependencies.cs" company="Google Inc.">
// Copyright (C) 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
//
//  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
//  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
//  You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
//  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
//  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
//  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
//  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
//    limitations under the License.
// </copyright>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;


/// Sample dependencies file.  Change the class name and dependencies as required by your project, then
/// save the file in a folder named Editor (which can be a sub-folder of your plugin).
///   There can be multiple dependency files like this one per project, the  resolver will combine them and process all
/// of them at once.
[InitializeOnLoad]
public class MyDependencies : AssetPostprocessor {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
  /// <summary>Instance of the PlayServicesSupport resolver</summary>
  public static object svcSupport;
#endif  // UNITY_ANDROID

  /// Initializes static members of the class.
    static MyDependencies() {

        //
        //
        // NOTE:
        //
        //       UNCOMMENT THIS CALL TO MAKE THE DEPENDENCIES BE REGISTERED.
        //   THIS FILE IS ONLY A SAMPLE!!
        //
          RegisterDependencies();
        //
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Registers the dependencies needed by this plugin.
  /// </summary>
  public static void RegisterDependencies() {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    RegisterAndroidDependencies();
#elif UNITY_IOS
    RegisterIOSDependencies();
#endif
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Registers the android dependencies.
  /// </summary>
  public static void RegisterAndroidDependencies() {

    // Setup the resolver using reflection as the module may not be
    // available at compile time.
    Type playServicesSupport = Google.VersionHandler.FindClass(
      "Google.JarResolver", "Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport");
    if (playServicesSupport == null) {
      return;
    }
    svcSupport = svcSupport ?? Google.VersionHandler.InvokeStaticMethod(
      playServicesSupport, "CreateInstance",
      new object[] {
          "GooglePlayGames",
          EditorPrefs.GetString("AndroidSdkRoot"),
          "ProjectSettings"
      });

    // For example to depend on play-services-games version 9.6.0  you need to specify the
    // package, artifact, and version as well as the packageId from the SDK manager in case
    // a newer version needs to be downloaded to build.

    Google.VersionHandler.InvokeInstanceMethod(
      svcSupport, "DependOn",
      new object[] {
      "com.google.android.gms",
      "play-services-games",
      "9.6.0" },
      namedArgs: new Dictionary<string, object>() {
          {"packageIds", new string[] { "extra-google-m2repository" } }
      });

    // This example gets the com.android.support.support-v4 library, version 23.1 or greater.
    // notice it is in a different package  than the play-services libraries.

    Google.VersionHandler.InvokeInstanceMethod(
      svcSupport, "DependOn",
      new object[] { "com.android.support", "support-v4", "23.1+" },
      namedArgs: new Dictionary<string, object>() {
          {"packageIds", new string[] { "extra-android-m2repository" } }
      });

    Google.VersionHandler.InvokeInstanceMethod(
      svcSupport, "DependOn",
            new object[] { "com.hyprmx.mediate", "HyprMediate-SDK", "1.1.0" });

  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Registers the IOS dependencies.
  /// </summary>
  public static void RegisterIOSDependencies() {

    // Setup the resolver using reflection as the module may not be
    // available at compile time.
    Type iosResolver = Google.VersionHandler.FindClass(
        "Google.IOSResolver", "Google.IOSResolver");
    if (iosResolver == null) {
      return;
    }

    // Dependencies for iOS are added by referring to CocoaPods.  The libraries and frameworkds are
    //  and added to the Unity project, so they will automatically be included.
    //
    // This example add the GooglePlayGames pod, version 5.0 or greater, disabling bitcode generation.

    Google.VersionHandler.InvokeStaticMethod(
      iosResolver, "AddPod",
      new object[] { "GooglePlayGames" },
      namedArgs: new Dictionary<string, object>() {
          { "version", "5.0+" },
          { "bitcodeEnabled", false },
      });
  }

  // Handle delayed loading of the dependency resolvers.
  private static void OnPostprocessAllAssets(
      string[] importedAssets, string[] deletedAssets,
      string[] movedAssets, string[] movedFromPath) {
    foreach (string asset in importedAssets) {
      if (asset.Contains("IOSResolver") ||
        asset.Contains("JarResolver")) {
        RegisterDependencies();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error in Unity: `Assets/Plugins/MyDependencies.cs(96,5): error CS0103: The name`Google' does not exist in the current context`

Any ideas how I can update the code such that Google does resolve so I can run the class? It seems like they've provided `dll`s to assist with this however I can't figure out how to get them to resolve. I tried to reference them using `using dll1` etc. but they didn't seem to be found.